# My aim is to import data from SQL and export it to Oracle Database. there might be thousands of records, so I am trying it using bulk import

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a SP at SQL side returning the required data. I need to export it to Oracle DB. I am using bulkcopy. here is the code.

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConnectionString");
string ConnectionStringOracle = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConnectionStringOracle");

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[SPNAME]", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();


        using (OracleConnection destinationConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStringOracle))
        {
            destinationConnection.Open();
            try
            {
                using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy(ConnectionStringOracle))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DESTTABLLENAME";                                                                                                                                  /                                   //bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1,1);
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(rdr);
                    bulkCopy.Close();
                    bulkCopy.Dispose();
                    destinationConnection.Dispose();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {

            }

        }
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am getting the following error :

oracle exception external component has thrown an exception

Comment: Is there any additional inner-exception or error codes to go with that?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Additional information: External component has thrown an exception. Thats all :(

Comment: Any Inputs ... I am struggling with it since last 13.5 hours :(

Comment: Not based on that; I'd start by looking at permissions, then the exact column mappings (is each the right size? are they in the same order? etc)

Comment: Your guess is absolutely right Marc. There was quite a few problem with table structure.1.There were spaces after column names. 2.NewGuid() in SQL did not match RAW() in Oracle. 3. I had written sequence and trigger to make PK column to be autogenerated. It was not working. [No idea why :(]4. It was not allowing me to insert empty values in few column. pheww. well issue is resolved now :D